# WPF - Webbrowser - getElementById

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, getelementbyid

In a WPF application, I have a webbrowser called WebBrowser1. This refers to an HTML page which contains a TextArea to which users can input text.

```
<html>
<body>
<textarea class="myStudentInput" id="myStudentInput1">
Text to be copied
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I wish to get this text and potentially also set this text.

I have tried something similar to the javascript way of writing it:

```
document.getElementById("myStudentOutput1").innerHTML;
```

such as

```
HtmlElement textArea = webBrowser1.Document.All["myStudentInput1"];

dynamic textArea = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByID("myStudentInput1").InnerText;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: include the relevant html please.

Comment: What's the line it fails on. when debugging are any of the values null?

Comment: It just says 'WebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'Document' and 'GetElementsbyId' and no extension method could be found (I'm new to C#).

Comment: Have a look at [debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx) for [visual studios](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEJ5xKO7c3o).

Comment: Why the down-votes? It's a valid question with a working example of the problem and the answer below shows there are non-trivial steps to be taken before the problem is solved.

Comment: As Hans Passant pointed out "it doesn't work." has no useful meaning. Have a look at [What have you tried](mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) and [how to ask](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you want a more in depth discussion then create a question on [meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution in Visual Studio 2015 WPF Application works for me.

First, add a reference to the Microsoft HTML COM Library.  This is on the COM tab, when you do an "Add Reference" in your project.

Then add the code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowser1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="480" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="770" Source="E:\Others\Dropbox\Programming\Questions.html"/>
        <Button x:Name="mySetQuestionButton" Content="Set Question" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,520,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="mySetQuestion"/>
        <Button x:Name="myGetAnswerButton" Content="Get Answer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,520,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="myGetAnswer"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="600,520,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void mySetQuestion(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mshtml.HTMLDocument document = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)WebBrowser1.Document;
            mshtml.IHTMLElement textArea = document.getElementById("myQuestion1");
            textArea.innerHTML = "What is 1+1?";
        }
        private void myGetAnswer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mshtml.HTMLDocument document = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)WebBrowser1.Document;
            mshtml.IHTMLElement textArea = document.getElementById("myStudentInput1");
            textBlock.Text = textArea.innerHTML;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> but it doesn't work.

I have no idea what that could possibly mean.  All you can get is a code snippet that does work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private WebBrowser webBrowser1;
    private Button button1;

    public Form1() {
        button1 = new Button { Text = "Test" };
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
        webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"<html><body><textarea class=""myStudentInput"" id=""myStudentInput1"">Text to be copied</textarea></body></html>";
        this.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myStudentInput1");
        MessageBox.Show(elem.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the effort though.