# Unable to access a generated DOM from a WPF WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I need to host a web page inside a WPF application, so I added a WPF `WebBrowser` control as follows...

```
<WebBrowser Name="WebBrowser" />
```

In the C#, I did the following...

```
WebBrowser.Navigate("http://tableau.visionrt.com/#/signin");
WebBrowser.LoadCompleted += PageLoadedLogin;
```

...and had the following method, in which I wanted to fill in the two inputs and submit the form...

```
private void PageLoadedLogin(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {
  IHTMLDocument3 doc = (IHTMLDocument3)WebBrowser.Document;
  HTMLInputElement u = (HTMLInputElement)doc.getElementById("username");
  HTMLInputElement p = (HTMLInputElement)doc.getElementById("password");
}
```

However, both `u` and `p` are null, meaning I can't access the elements. I can see the elements if I view the source in a a browser, but I can't access them in code.

I tried the following, just in case I'd got the names wrong...

```
IHTMLElementCollection inputs = doc.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

...but that didn't find anything.

Now, looking at the actual HTML that the URL returns, it looks like the `<input>` and `<button>` elements are generated in JavaScript, in which case they may not have been created when the `LoadCompleted` event fires.

So, I tried adding a call to `Thread.Sleep` in a quick-and-dirty way of making sure the JavaScript had had time to create the elements, but it didn't make any difference.

I tried using the HtmlAgilityPack as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918745/c-sharp-wpf-webbrowser-mshtml-explore-dom-find-elements), but that gave the same lack of results as above.

Anyone any ideas why I can't access generated elements? All of this works fine on a page with static HTML.

Comment: Have you tried `WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById()` without casting it to `IHTMLDocument3`?

Comment: @garryman It shows `GetElementById` in red, with the message _'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementById'_... Without casting it, `Document` is an object

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664932/wpf-webbrowser-getelementbyid

Comment: @garryman Thanks, but I tried that one as well, and it doesn't find the input element.